# auto number returned rows from select query to populate listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating a highscore list in my android app. I am returning the top ten high scores in order, and would like to auto number them so I can get them in the format:

`1 name score

2 name score

3 name score

4 ...`

with the ranking of the score (1,2,3,4 etc) coming from the order of the returned rows. I am using this cursor to populate a listview, so is it possible to do this as part of the query? Or is there another solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a `CursorAdapter`? If you are, you can do this, can't you?

```
bindView(View view, Cursor cursor){  
  ((TextView)view).setText(cursor.getPosition() + " " + cursor.getString(DATA_COLUMN)); 
}
```

Comment: Excellent, i didn't know about the getPosition function, thanks you